# Cassandra custom type mapping?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I'd like to be able to do a custom serialization/deserialization of raw types with cassandra without needing to make UDT.  Basically I want to store a string column, but have it automatically deserialized into a String wrapper value I have.  Is there any way to hook into the cassandra mapping code? I looked through it and I didn't see a particular opening where to put in a custom mapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to plug in a custom mapping mechanism into the Java driver, but [JAVA-721](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-721) is scheduled for 2.1.7 and will probably bring you the ability you are looking for.

Comment: FYI JAVA-721 couldn't make into 2.1.7 but has been included in 2.2.0-rc2, which has been released today.

Comment: What's the release cycle for release candidates? Is -rc2 stable to go to prod with?

Comment: No, you should wait until 2.2.0 goes GA before going to prod with it. On the other hand we do want our users to test 2.2.0-rc2 as much as they can, specially custom codecs, so that we get all the feedback we can before going GA.